Staking through proxy
I am working on a project at bittensor blockchain, where I have delegated my wallet to a proxy address allow proxy to perform staking ops on delegated wallets' behalf.
But when I am trying to stake with proxy wallet it is not functionaing as expected, Although it shows trx successful.
Please can any one suggest me the solution
// tx object for staking
const call = (await api).tx.subtensorModule.addStake(
      validatorAccount,
      amountToStake
    );

// tx obj, for stake on behalf of delegateAddr
const stakeTx = (await api).tx.proxy.proxy(
      delegateAddr,
      "Staking",
      call
    );

// Sign and submit the tx
return new Promise<{ hash: string; status: boolean }>((resolve, reject) => {
      s.signAndSend(proxyAccount, async (result: SubmittableResult) => {
        if (result.status.isFinalized) {
          console.log(`Stake finalized in block ${result.status.asFinalized}`);
          console.log(" ~ .signAndSend ~ result:", result);
          // result.isFinalized
          resolve({ hash: `${result}`, status: true });
        } else if (result.isError) {
          console.error("Error in staking transaction:", result);
          reject(new Error("Error in staking transaction"));
        }
      }).catch((error: Error) => {
        reject(error);
        throw error;
      });
    });


Double-check that the proxyAccount is correctly set
up with the necessary permissions to perform staking operations on
behalf of the delegateAddr. Ensure that the proxy type ("Staking")
is properly configured.
After the transaction is finalized, query the blockchain state to confirm that the staking operation was applied correctly. This will help you verify whether the stake was actually added to the validatorAccount.
